# mock guid-typescript with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm using guid-typescript as a class for representing Guids. I want to fake those Guids, so in my Jest tests the Guid has always the same value (like '12345'). So that I can compare the expected and real result correctly. The method "create" returns a GUID-Object itself.

Basically I tried this in my spec file, but it seems to return "undefined" instead of a Guid-Object with the value '1234'.

```
import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';
jest.mock('guid-typescript');

...
describe('customer Tests', () => {
it('should create a new customer', () => {
    const fakeGuid = Guid.parse('1234');
    jest.spyOn(Guid, 'create').mockReturnValue(fakeGuid);
...
// Create a customer object
// save it
// etc
});
});
```

Comment: Remove `jest.mock('guid-typescript');`.

Comment: thank you... this worked. do you have a good recommondation for a tutorial ... the ones I checked and the documentation didnt really help me. thank you